# Creating a zip file from a JSON object using adm-zip

Tags: json, node.js, adm-zip

I'm trying to create a `.zip` file from a JSON object in Node.js. I'm using [adm-zip to do that](https://github.com/cthackers/adm-zip) however I'm unable to make it work with this code:

```
var admZip = require('adm-zip');
var zip = new admZip();
zip.addFile(Date.now() + '.json', new Buffer(JSON.stringify(jsonObject));
var willSendthis = zip.toBuffer();
fs.writeFileSync('./example.zip', willSendthis);
```

This code creates `example.zip` but I'm not able to extract it, I tried with a `.zip`extractor but also with this code:

```
var admZip = require('adm-zip');
var zip = new admZip("./example.zip");
var zipEntries = zip.getEntries(); // an array of ZipEntry records

zipEntries.forEach(function(zipEntry) {
    console.log(zipEntry.data.toString('utf8')); 
});
```

It returns `Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined` at the line with `console.log`.

I could use `zip.writeZip()` for this example but I'm sending the `.zip`file to Amazon S3 thus I need to use the method `.toBuffer()` to do something like this after using `adm-zip`:

```
var params = {Key: 'example.zip', Body: zip.toBuffer()};
s3bucket.upload(params, function(err, data) {...});
```

I don't see what is wrong, am I using the package correctly?

Comment: can you read the json file in `example.zip` after writing to disk?

Answer (score 1):

Try use `zipEntry.getData().toString('utf8')` instead `zipEntry.data.toString('utf8')`:

```
var admZip = require('adm-zip');
var zip = new admZip("./example.zip");
var zipEntries = zip.getEntries(); // an array of ZipEntry records

zipEntries.forEach(function(zipEntry) {
    console.log(zipEntry.getData().toString('utf8')); 
});
```

Comment: It's returning only 2/3 of the file that has been added to the zip, I don't understand as the functions are synchronous.